# Textbox_Enter event not does nothing

Tags: c#, winforms, text, enter

I want to be able to tell when the user cliked on a textbox and is in "edit" mode. Everywhere I look I see the textbox_Enter and textbox_Leave events being used with the instructions within that and it works fine. For me however it doesn't do anything. I tried elimination as many outside factors as possible, including creating a brand new project just for testing purposes and copied some code samples yet again nothing happens when I click on the textbox. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 with Visual C# Application Windows Form (.NET Framework)

Also here's a sample of the code I try to use if it helps for whatever reason

```
private void textbox_Enter(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    label.Text = "ok";
}
```

Comment: Did you register the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the type of the `e` parameter is not correct: It must be `EventArgs`, not `ControlEventArgs`:

```
private void textbox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Second, you need to register the event in the forms designer with the textbox control in the properties window:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to wire up this method to the textbox enter event. Select the control and then look at the events section in the properties tab.